# NSView - draw on top

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Working on a music player. I have an NSTableView with a bunch of NSTableCellViews, which each have an NSSlider that unhides when that track starts playing.

Now the problem is, we want the slider to draw right at the bottom of the NSTableCellView, but that means that the knobRect overlaps with the NSTableCellView below it. What is the best way to make sure the knob draws on top of the other table cell views?

[image: Image overlap]

Comment: Why don't you just make the height for that cell a little taller instead?

Comment: @MatthewBurke We need consistent row heights. I guess we could simultaneously increase the row height for one and decrease for another while the slider is visible while appearing the same to the user, but that wouldn't be my ideal solution.

Comment: yeah, that's more or less what I had in mind. Stopped typing too quickly. While perhaps not ideal, I think your only other alternative is to put the slider view in the table (or its scroll view). And that's going to be a huge headache.

Comment: @MatthewBurke Cool, thanks for the comments. I have more experience in web dev so was hoping for some kind of z-index like property. This will do fine, just a little more work. Leave it as the answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting row heights is going to be the easiest thing. (especially if you only allow one playback at a time :))

You could try the setFloatsGroupRows: method of NSTableView and NSTableViewDelegate method tableView:isGroupRow:
This combo gives some very unique built in customizations, but from the looks of it, you've already customized a fair amount so you should be capable.

Also you could try what they wrap which is actually NSScrollView's addFloatingSubview:forAxis:
However, that said, NSTableView and the hierarchy it lives in are pretty tightly wound together so you may find this behaves very oddly with NSTableView when you're not doing the floating group row thing.

In the end, you might want to just revisit your UI design. Maybe your scroller could be like this where the edge of a color ramp is your slider so you can fit it right on top of the playing track :
[image: example slider]